# how to fix ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: when trying to install pyp2p on windows

Tags: python, installation, pip

when running the command:
`pip install pyp2p`
I receive to following error:

```
Collecting pyp2p
  Using cached pyp2p-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Collecting pyroute2>=0.3.15
  Using cached pyroute2-0.5.14.tar.gz (873 kB)
Collecting ntplib>=0.3.3
  Using cached ntplib-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.9 kB)
Collecting ipaddress>=1.0.14
  Using cached ipaddress-1.0.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.8.1 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pyp2p) (2.24.0)
Collecting netifaces>=0.10.4
  Using cached netifaces-0.10.9.tar.gz (28 kB)
Collecting twisted>=15.4.0
  Using cached Twisted-20.3.0.tar.bz2 (3.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: win_inet_pton in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pyroute2>=0.3.15->pyp2p) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.8.1->pyp2p) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.8.1->pyp2p) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.8.1->pyp2p) (1.25.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.8.1->pyp2p) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.4.2 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from twisted>=15.4.0->pyp2p) (5.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from twisted>=15.4.0->pyp2p) (15.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=16.10.1 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from twisted>=15.4.0->pyp2p) (17.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from twisted>=15.4.0->pyp2p) (20.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from twisted>=15.4.0->pyp2p) (21.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyHamcrest!=1.10.0,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from twisted>=15.4.0->pyp2p) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from twisted>=15.4.0->pyp2p) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from Automat>=0.3.0->twisted>=15.4.0->pyp2p) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.4.2->twisted>=15.4.0->pyp2p) (53.0.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for netifaces, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyroute2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for twisted, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: twisted, pyroute2, ntplib, netifaces, ipaddress, pyp2p
    Running setup.py install for twisted ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\woutv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5hfmjmxi\\twisted_4f16cdfbaea243e282e7aa8a376189e6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\woutv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5hfmjmxi\\twisted_4f16cdfbaea243e282e7aa8a376189e6\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\woutv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y_l6uo1b\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\twisted'
         cwd: C:\Users\woutv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5hfmjmxi\twisted_4f16cdfbaea243e282e7aa8a376189e6\
    Complete output (955 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted
```

than there are A LOT of lines that look almost identical to this : `copying src\twisted\conch\unix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\conch`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
    raiser.c
    c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\woutv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5hfmjmxi\\twisted_4f16cdfbaea243e282e7aa8a376189e6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\woutv\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5hfmjmxi\\twisted_4f16cdfbaea243e282e7aa8a376189e6\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\woutv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y_l6uo1b\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\woutv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Anyone know how to fix this?
I dont know if this is enough information so dont hesitate to ask for more info.

Comment: That line alone doesn't help. We need the entire backtrace.

Comment: I edited the post to include most of the backtrace.

Comment: I checked for you and looks like there's a wheel issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000214/how-do-i-pip-install-twisted-without-getting-an-error